# Change Matlabs default missing-semicolon behaviour to use `datatipinfo` instead of `disp`

Tags: matlab, interactive

A common annoyance in Matlab is that, if one forgets the semicolon, one might be flooded with megabytes of numbers in the interactive shell. Matlab calls `disp(...)` on any unsurpressed output, which can be quite painful. The output of `datatipinfo(...)` is much more friendly.

- Is it possible to change Matlabs behaviour to call `datatipinfo` rather than `disp` on unsurpressed output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

If you are working with MATLAB objects, you can overload `disp` to make it display whatever you want, which could include the use of `datatipinfo`. But in general no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of modifying `disp` command for Matlab. It has nasty side-effects, for example it will not work in compiled code.

**My best advice is simply don't forget the semicolon.**
If you need to display something, just use `disp`.